# PgRouting in GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pgrouting

Is there any good reason why the pgrouting extension is still not supported by GCP Cloud SQL? I mean, Cloud SQL even supports PostGIS 2.3 version.

Also, considering I already have PostGIS 2.3 installed on Cloud SQL, is there any way I could install pgrouting manually without issuing the CREATE EXTENSION statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way you can install pgRouting manually without using the CREATE EXTENSION statement, and as you already know, it's currently not supported unfortunately.

However, I was able to find a public feature request open **[here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63537525)** for pgRouting to be supported by PostgreSQL (in CloudSQL). You could comment and follow updates there on the potential support for it in future.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 26th of August, [pgRouting is now supported](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#August_26_2022) in Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL.